# Joomla - Migrating from 1.5 to 2.5 - <jdoc:include type="component" /> not rendering content in revised 2.5 template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

We are migrating (*migraining I should say*) from 1.5 to 2.5 and our revised template from 1.5 is working, except it won't display any content when using . Please help!

Here is the code:

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"> <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/home.html"><img src="images/stories/blank.gif" width="180" height="93" border="0" alt="Home"></a>
        <div id="hdnav">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="headnav" style="none" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <div id="topnav">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topnav" style="none" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="maincontent">
          <jdoc:include type="message" />
          <jdoc:include type="component" />
        </div>
        <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
        <div id="rightcol">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough to work with. Unless someone spots a syntax error in your code, there's nothing else we can possible do for you.

Comment: your error may be on another place, not in this code. did you do com_content overrides? is there anything in the error log?

Comment: oh no! so sorry! I'm migrating someone else's code.  Just realized they did, in fact, have com_content overrides, which I'm not as familiar with. Not quite sure what they were trying to do.  I removed them and now content is rendering, but it's rendering as divs, where the original developers had it in tables (at least, wrote their css to that), so doesn't match the old site exactly. Guess I'll have to rewrite the style sheet to have the divs match the style of the tables in the old site, correct?  Sorry again for my confusion and not supplying enough information.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: either that, or you have to make new overrides. maybe even both

Comment: oh boy!  Would you happen to know any good guides on overrides?  I haven't found many good ones yet.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. styles

Please take the time to write new css for the divs.  Tables are ancient and break easily and are a total nightmare on mobile devices.

1. overrides

If you do 1. you won't need them.  Anyhow they're really easy.

A template override is simply a component or module view template which is copied under the your template's html subfolder (in a slightly different folder structure) and Joomla will use those instead of the original files.
So for example if you want to override article view, which is in

```
/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/
```

its override would be placed in

```
/templates/your_template/html/com_content/article
```

One small catch: Make sure you always copy the whole tmpl folder of components, you must override all layouts inside the template.

You can find more info on
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help, Riccardo!  Yes, I totally agree, there shouldn't be any tables.  I shuddered when I saw the old code for this site!   But I guess they hadn't updated it in many years.